# Wrong value for a local variable in a minidump

Tags: c++, windbg, minidump

One of my C++ applications crashed and I got a minidump. The application was compiled in release with all sorts of optimizations. The "Characteristics" value when I execute !lmi in WinDbg is 2022 (I don't know what this means, sorry). The minidump shows that the piece of code which threw the unhandled exception was something like this:

```
size_t idx = GetValue();
someOtherVar = someVector[idx];
```

I am sure that someVector has at least one element and analyzing the minidump with winDbg it says that the value of the local variable idx is 0x0. In addition, the execution of dv /V in winDbg says that idx is stored in @r10.

I can find an explanation for this crash for values of idx > 0, but not if idx == 0. Is it possible that variable idx had been optimized and the real value used to access someVector were greater than 0?

Comment: Optimized code can do all sorts of things. You'll want to look at the disassembly to see what's really going on. How certain are you that the `someVector` value is correct? That could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Trace back through the disassembly, often the broken values are sourced from elsewhere (stack variables or other registers)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I'm pretty sure that `someVector` has at least 1 element because of my previous code.

Comment: "the unhandled exception was something like this:" - no. What you gave us is code, not an exception. What exception is stored in the crash dump? Why don't you look at the value of `someVector`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller thank you for your contribution. If you read carefully my question, I wrote _the piece of code which threw the unhandled exception..._ The exception was an "index out of bounds" exception in that vector. The example code is very simplified and the minidump didn't show me the contents of the real `someVector`. Anyway, I dissasembled my app and now I'm sure that some of the registers have been zeroed in the minidump. So, it probably made the same with r10. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @JMMorales make sure you set the public Microsoft symbol server path (.symfix+) as well as the path to your binary's PDB.